# Can there be multiple container tables in Zurb Ink?

Tags: zurb-ink

[Zurb Ink's](http://zurb.com/ink/) [grid](http://zurb.com/ink/docs.php#grid) requires a `table.container` element at the top-most level to contain rows and columns. However, it's not clear to me if there should only be one `table.container` for the whole email – kind of like a `<body>` tag. Or is it is better practice to have multiple containers, one for each section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
table.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: inherit;
  width: 580px;
}
```

Look at the CSS code for `table.container` It is used to create a fixed width layout which centers the content.

Now coming to your question, Look in the documentation for `Reverse Row Syntax`. It is a indication that tells you that you can ***use multiple containers*** if you need to restrict the full width row.

- If you have a fixed width layout throughout, use **table.container at
  the top**.
- If you have variable length elements, use **table.container at each
  section** if you want to restrict the width for the content.